# Integral proof of an exponent property.

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, formal-proofs

Let function $f$ be continuous everywhere. Prove or disprove (by finding a counter example) that: $$
\ \int (f(x))^2 \, dx = \left(\int f(x) \, dx\right)^2 $$

I'm not really sure how to go about this problem, would it require a Darboux / Riemann proof? Anything helps. Thanks.

Comment: Can you find an example where it **IS** true? If not, perhaps a counter example.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales : It is true of every function taking nonzero values only in the interval $[0,1]$ (or any other set of $\text{measure 1.} \qquad$

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=x$. Them LHS $=\frac {x^{3}} 3+C$ and RHS $=(\frac {x^{2}} 2+C)^{2}$. Are these equal ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try $f(x)=1$ to disprove the claim.
It gives
$$\int f^2(x)\,dx=\int dx=x+c$$
$$\left(\int f(x) \, dx\right)^2=(x+c)^2$$
The claim is false.